# Post image file and string text parameters using NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

im new to iOS. and im trying to post some data using POST method including image file. `picture` is the last parameter

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"first_name=%@&last_name=%@&email=%@password=%@&picture",[_firstName text],[[_lastName text],[_email text],[_password text],[What to Add Here]];
    NSLog(@"%@",post);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.test.com/ws/customer/authenticate"];
```

`//Additional info`

```
   NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];


            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            //[request setValue:postLength forKey:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
```

Can i just use image path like `@"demo.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution is to:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: "demo.png"];
NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
// request
...
[request setHTTPBody: dataImage];
```

In your case you can use base64:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: "demo.png"];
NSData *dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *stringImage = [dataImage base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"first_name=%@&last_name=%@&email=%@password=%@&picture",[_firstName text],[[_lastName text],[_email text],[_password text], stringImage];
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should convert image data to string format and use as paramter,If you directly use this string value we cant retrive image correctly.So replace '+' character from image string with any value(like @"sdfs4546dgdggdterteradv").Then backend should replace this value to "+" and store.